# How to handle specific case Java variable length arguments in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, interop, cascading

I'm trying to port some Java code to Clojure and I ran into a situation that I can't solve.

Normally when you want call a Java constructor or method with a variable length argument you do something like this

```
(Fields. (into-array Comparable ["predict", "other"]))
```

However I found a special example where this doesn't work:

```
(Fields. (into-array Comparable ["predict", Double]))
```

Although this seems possible in Java (see below), the code above gives the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException array element type mismatch  java.lang.reflect.Array.set (Array.java:-2)
```

I tried a couple of variations, but nothing seems to work. The Java code I try to port (and the specific line that gives trouble) is here https://github.com/Cascading/pattern/blob/wip-1.0/pattern-examples/src/main/java/cascading/pattern/Main.java#L76

```
new Fields( "predict", Double.class )
```

(The constructor signature for Fields is Fields(Comparable... fields) http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/tuple/Fields.html#Fields(java.lang.Comparable...)

I tried the following examples in the Clojure repl:

```
(into-array Comparable [(type Double)])
(into-array Comparable [Double/TYPE])
(into-array Comparable [Double])
=>
IllegalArgumentException array element type mismatch  java.lang.reflect.Array.set (Array.java:-2)
```

Comment: Which variations? In the Java case the 2nd parameter is a *class*. I'm not fluent in Clojure, have you tried something like Double.class, Double.type, (class Double), (type Double)?

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why this works in Java. Double.class should be of type Class, which does not implement Comparable. Unfortunately I don't have a Java compiler at hand to check that.

Comment: @Berrylium Yeah basically those. Thanks I updated the question.

Comment: @RafałDowgird I'm puzzled too, but the Java code is able to run locally.

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk Tried to reproduce it in an online Java compiler and failed. See my answer for details.

Comment: This is interesting as the Cascading code compiles through graddle.. See other comment

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to pass `Double.class` as `Comparable` in Java and got this:

```
Line: 4
foo(java.lang.Comparable...) in HelloWorld cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<java.lang.Double>)
```

Here's the code I tried to compile:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void foo(Comparable... args) {}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo("predict",Double.class);

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafal, could you try this as well:

git clone git@github.com:Cascading/pattern.git;
cd pattern-examples;
gradle clean jar;
ls build/classes/main/cascading/pattern/Main.class

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `Field` class constructor code in cascading I guess you should be fine to port this specific line as:

`(into-array Comparable ["predict" 0.0])`

Comment: In the current ported code I actually have (Fields. (into-array ["predict", "1.0"])) and this doesn't give any error. My concern is that I can put any Comparable there and it doesn't break, so the Double.class variant might only be required in a specific edge case. I'll have to ask the creators of Cascading Pattern